# Passing reference type objects and changing the values

Tags: c#, methods, interface, reference-type

I am trying to pass reference type object into a method and changing it from there. When I change it I don't have that change on the variable which is passed to method.

Here is the example:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Teacher : IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

//......

public void CreateTeacher(IPerson teacher)
{
    teacher = new Teacher() { Name = "Teacher name", LastName = "Teacher's last name"};
}
//.....

//I am trying this, but after I call CreateTeacher() variable teacher is null
IPerson teacher=null;
CreateTeacher(teacher);
string n = teacher.Name;
```

After running `CreateTeacher()` variable teacher is still null? Can anyone explain why?
I know I could return `IPerson` on my `CreateTeacher()` method or use `out`, but I can't use them.

The `IPerson` interface is in a different dll and `Teacher` class is in a different dll. The method `CreateTeacher` is the same dll where class is.

**UPDATE:**

Here is something else I tried:

```
  IPerson teacher=new Teacher();
  CreateTeacher(teacher);
  string n = teacher.Name;//I have the changes here now

  //......

    public void CreateTeacher(IPerson teacher)
    {
        ((Teacher)teacher).Name = "My Name";
    }
```

What is the difference between 1st example and 2nd? Is it because of the passed value was `null`?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why cannot you use `return` here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to RedPolygon's answer.. I feel like this might clear things up.

As explained, you're changing the value of the reference.. not the object pointed to by the reference.

Change your code to this:

```
public interface IPerson {
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public void CreateTeacher(IPerson teacher) {
    teacher.Name = "Teacher name";
}

IPerson teacher = new Teacher();
CreateTeacher(teacher);
```

..that will work. Why? A couple of reasons.

1. It isn't `null` anymore, we "`new` it up".
2. You aren't "`new`'ing it up" in the `CreateTeacher` method, thereby pointing the copied reference at an entirely new object. This means you're changing the object pointed to by both of your references.

It's confusing.. yes, but you understand it when you have a play around with examples like this.

EDIT:

I had to fire up paint and put my awesome MSPaint skills on display:

This is your first snippet flow:

[image: Pass by value for reference types 1]

This is my snippet (and your second one):

[image: Pass by value for reference types 2]

Comment: Hopefully my incredible diagrams also help :P

Answer (score 7):

C# passes by values, not references. In your case, you are passing by value a reference which you are trying to change. You want to explicitly say that you want to pass by reference your reference using `ref` keyword:

```
public void CreateTeacher(ref IPerson teacher)
{
    teacher = new Teacher() { Name = "Teacher name", LastName = "Teacher's last name"};
}
```

Or better yet:

```
public Teacher CreateTeacher()
{
    return new Teacher() { Name = "Teacher name", LastName = "Teacher's last name"};
}
```

Comment: Pass-by-value and pass-by-reference semantics are often confused exactly like this when people see the term "reference type". +1

Comment: This link explains it well : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @Dilshod in your update, you're still passing by value a reference, but you don't change the reference there! you're changing the value which is "pointed" by the reference (there is no pointer here but you know what I mean). Your issue is that you're trying to change directly the reference itself, not the object referenced.

Comment: @RedPolygon that makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: @RomainMeresse dead link :(

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck the content can be found here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/0f66670z (archive http://archive.is/vblkz)