# Action<T> assign value to variable

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, action

I have an action

```
Action<string> removeTitle = source => { source = RemoveTitle(source); };
```

Which I invoke

```
string name = "MR JOHN DOE"
removeTitle(name);
```

But does not change the variable `name`

VS (possibly Resharper) said "*Value assigned is not used in any execution path*" for `source` after the lambda separator.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable.. so your reference is being re-created within the scope of the lambda. It is a [similar issue to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366499/passing-reference-type-objects-and-changing-the-values/17366764).

You need to return it via a `Func<T1, T2>` delegate if you want to modify it, but you can't use `ref` or `out` (as suggested in that question) unless you create your own delegate type (Note: I have shortened it via method grouping):

```
Func<string, string> removeTitle = RemoveTitle;

// ...
name = removeTitle(name);
```

Comment: Definitely the better way to go, but you can use `ref`/`out` in a lambda, however you can't convert it to a delegate in the Func/Action family of delegates since `ref`/`out` is part of the signature. You need to define your own delegate type that is compatible. It also requires all argument types to be specified in the lambda.

Comment: Thats what I meant. Will update when back at my desk. Thanks mike!

Answer (score 1):

You can capture `name` variable in `Action...` delegate and change it if it work in your particular context:

```
string name = "something";
Action<string> removeTitle = source => { name = RemoveTitle(source); };

removeTitle(name);
```

I would recommend to go with `Func<string, string>` as suggested by Simon Whitehead's answer if it is possible as code that does not capture local variable and just returns result without side effects is easier to reason about:

```
Func<string,string> removeTitle = RemoveTitle;  
name = removeTitle(name);
```